# Undefined reference to make_unique (my define)

Tags: c++, c++11

I have followed the instructions in [this question/answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63249/50647) and I have created a template class:

```
// ConfigItems.hpp
#pragma once    
#include <memory>
#include <string>

template< typename T > class ConfigItem : public IConfigItem // here IConfigItem is the class that has the virtual members
{
private:
    T m_value;

public:
    ConfigItem< T >(const T& valueIn = 0);

    std::ostream &printTo(std::ostream &outIn) const;
    operator T() const;
};

template< typename T, typename ...Args > std::unique_ptr< T > make_unique(Args&& ...args);
```

Implementation is here:

```
// ConfigItems.cpp
#include "ConfigItems.hpp"

template< typename T > ConfigItem< T >::ConfigItem(const T& valueIn) : m_value(valueIn) {}

template< typename T > ConfigItem< T >::operator T() const
{
    return m_value;
}

template< typename T > std::ostream& ConfigItem< T >::printTo(std::ostream& outIn) const
{
    return outIn << m_value;
}
template< typename T, typename ...Args > std::unique_ptr< T > make_unique(Args&& ...args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr< T >(new T(std::forward< Args >(args)...));
}
```

And I have created a ConfigFile class:

```
// ConfigFile.hpp
#pragma once
class ConfigFile
{
private:
    static const std::string sm_inputFolderPath;

    std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr< IConfigItem > > m_configMap;

public:
    ConfigFile(const std::string& nameIn);
    ~ConfigFile();

};
```

Implementation:

```
// ConfigFile.cpp
#include "ConfigFile.hpp"

const std::string ConfigFile::sm_inputFolderPath = "input_folder_path";

ConfigFile::ConfigFile(const std::string& nameIn)
{
    PTree tmpPT;
    json::read_json(nameIn, tmpPT);

    m_configMap.emplace(
        ConfigFile::sm_inputFolderPath,
        make_unique< ConfigItem< std::string > >(tmpPT.get< std::string >(ConfigFile::sm_inputFolderPath))); // here I get the error
}
```

I am getting a linking error (not compiling):

```
undefined reference to `std::unique_ptr<ConfigItem<std::string>, std::default_delete<ConfigItem<std::string> > > make_unique<ConfigItem<std::string>, std::string>(std::string&&)'
```

I am not sure what is the problem here. I am using c++11, that is why I have added the function of `make_unique`. Can anyone help me to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `make_unique` defined in a header file that you include? Or do you just include the declaration?

Comment: In other words, it would be much easier to understand what's wrong if the code you show would already compile and exhibit the problem.

Comment: Dumb question, did you `#include <memory>`?

Comment: yes, I have included `memory`. Is the function redefined?

Comment: Please show us a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: please tell me what shall I add more?

Comment: Move the definition in hpp should fix your issue. see [why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)